# Division on multiple columns pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am a pandas df and I need to do mass division between ~50 columns

```
 Age  Rosedale   Rosedale_y   Trinity  Trinity_y.....etc until 50 more columns   
 0    1          100
 1    3          106
 2    2          109
 3    3          108
```

How do I divide columns such as

- Rosedale by Rosedale_y
- Trinity by Trinity_y

Desired

```
Age   Rosedale_rate   Trinity_rate
0     0.01
1     0.03
2     0.02
3     0.03
```

Comment: `df.Rosedale /df.Rosedale_y`

Comment: @mad_ ... OP is asking mass division across ~50 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` makes it easy to select the columns you need, followed by one final division.

```
df = df.set_index('Age')

i = df.filter(regex=r'_y$')
j = df[df.columns.difference(i.columns)]
i.columns = j.columns.str.split('_y').str[0]

df = j / i.reindex(j.columns, axis=1)
```

The `reindex` is for added security to make sure both DataFrames are aligned.

Comment: That regex can be `_y$` so it's guaranteed to end with `_y` and not somehow match `_y` anywhere in the column name (unlikely - but - you're being safe with the `reindex` :) Your current regex is the equivalent of using `like='_y'`...

Comment: @JonClements Thank you!